# Postgres runs out of memory with trigger

Tags: postgresql, triggers, postgis

I have two tables:

```
CREATE TABLE foo (
    id serial primary key,
    abc text
);

CREATE TABLE bar (
    id serial primary key,
    xyz text
);
```

I have a trigger on table `foo`:

```
CREATE FUNCTION foo_before_insert()
    RETURNS trigger AS
    $BODY$
        BEGIN

        INSERT INTO bar (id, xyz)
        VALUES (
            NEW.id,
            FooFunction(NEW.abc)
        );

        RETURN NEW;

        END;
    $BODY$

    LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
    COST 100;

CREATE TRIGGER foo_before_insert
    BEFORE INSERT ON foo
    EXECUTE PROCEDURE foo_before_insert();
```

So when something is inserted into `foo`, something is also inserted into `bar`, with the `abc` column being manipulated by `FooFunction`. That's the simplified version.

The real-world `FooFunction` takes two numeric arguments for longitude and latitude, does a `for loop` with a `SELECT` query selecting a single geometry column, does some Postgis functions with the geometry column and the input, and returns a boolean. Basically, the function is trying to determine if a point is inside at least one polygon from a set of polygons.

Here's the meat and potatoes of the function:

```
    FOR currentLinestring IN
        SELECT linestring
        FROM   bla
        WHERE  yadda yadda...
    LOOP
        currentLinestring = ST_MakeLine(currentLinestring);

        -- Can't make polygon with under 4 points
        IF ST_NPoints(currentLinestring) < 4 THEN
            EXIT;
        END IF;

        IF ST_Contains(ST_MakePolygon(currentLinestring), ST_SetSRID(ST_MakePoint(_lon, _lat), 4326)) = TRUE THEN
            -- Is not out of bounds
            RETURN FALSE;
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    -- Is out of bounds
    RETURN TRUE;
```

The catch is the function works 100% fine when outside the trigger (like mass updates) but when inside the trigger function the memory usage of Postgres climbs and climbs until all memory is exhausted and Postgres crashes. This is happening when I'm `COPY`ing a large CSV with maybe 100k rows.

What's causing this to happen? How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

The first important question is if the memory gets freed as soon as the transaction commits (try with a smaller CSV file). If that is not the case, it makes the problem much worse.

The next thing to examine is the memory dump in the PostgreSQL server log which looks somewhat like this:

```
TopMemoryContext: 221952 total in 17 blocks; 7440 free (41 chunks); 214512 used
   TopTransactionContext: 8192 total in 1 blocks; 6384 free (0 chunks); 1808 used
     CurTransactionContext: 0 total in 0 blocks; 0 free (0 chunks); 0 used
   Type information cache: 24240 total in 2 blocks; 3744 free (0 chunks); 20496 used
   RI compare cache: 24576 total in 2 blocks; 15984 free (5 chunks); 8592 used
...
```

See which memory context has all that memory.

You should ensure that you have a recently patched PostgreSQL and PostGIS installation.

Chances are that the memory gets leaked in some PostGIS function.
Try to narrow that down as much as possible by eliminating some of the functions until you know which one is the culprit.

Then create a simple test case for people to reproduce the problem and report the problem to PostGIS (or PostgreSQL if you can reproduce the problem without PostGIS), including all your findings (which memory context, …).

That's the best way to solve this problem if you cannot work around it, e.g. by splitting the work into multiple transactions.

Comment: Personally I suspect it's just a recursive trigger that's hitting memory limits before it exhausts the stack depth limit.

Comment: @CraigRinger I thought about this as a possibility but I don't believe that's the case. In the trigger function I removed the call to FooFunction and the insert went fine. FooFunction is only doing a SELECT so I'm not sure how it could cause a recursive trigger.

Comment: PostGIS is known to be a memory hog occasionally.